# Unsatisfied `Default` trait bound on type required by standard library

Tags: rust, traits, type-traits, rust-web3

I'm using a type from the [`web3` crate](https://crates.io/crates/web3), `web3::contract::Contract<web3::transports::Http>`. The compiler is complaining with [`E0277`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0277):

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling proj v0.1.0 (/home/user/proj)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `web3::contract::Contract<web3::transports::Http>: Default` is not satisfied
  --> src/book.rs:38:5
   |
38 | /     #[serde(skip)]
39 | |     abi: web3::contract::Contract<OMETransport>,
   | |_______________________________________________^ the trait `Default` is not implemented for `web3::contract::Contract<web3::transports::Http>`
   |
   = note: required by `std::default::Default::default`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `proj`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

How can this error originate from `std::default::Default::default`?

The definition for the relevant type (i.e., the struct containing the `web3` type) is:

```rust
/// Represents an order book for a particular market
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Book {
    market: Address, /* the address of the market */
    bids: BTreeMap<U256, VecDeque<Order>>, /* buy-side */
    asks: BTreeMap<U256, VecDeque<Order>>, /* sell-side */
    #[serde(serialize_with = "from_hex_se", deserialize_with = "from_hex_de")]
    ltp: U256, /* last traded price */
    depth: (usize, usize), /* depth  */
    crossed: bool,   /* is book crossed? */
    #[serde(serialize_with = "from_hex_se", deserialize_with = "from_hex_de")]
    spread: U256, /* bid-ask spread */
    #[serde(skip)]
    abi: web3::contract::Contract<web3::transports:Http>,
}
```

Comment: If the field is skipped, it will be omitted from serialized data. What should it be set to when deserializing this serialized data?

Comment: You're correct - did you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 5):

the [serde documentation](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#skip) for `#[serde(skip)]` says:

> When deserializing, Serde will use Default::default() or the function given by default = "..." to get a default value for this field.